# Python - why the button sometime works and sometime fails to execute all the logic assigned?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

In my python script i have such button, its very weired when i press the button, it sometimes works but sometimes fails to do the self.buttononTop() call and takes a while to execute `subprocess.call(...)` only what it does correctly is the part `urllib2.urlopen` all the rest fails, its not stable. What is causing it to get fail sometime and sometime it works? I have updated the linux kernel for this too but it seems same no improvement.

any idea?

```
  def disconnectButton(self, w):
    print "Window Resize"
    self.buttononTop()
    """URL url = new URL("http://"
            + my_main_server
            + "/a/disconnectusername?username="
            + my_main_username
            + "&password="
            + my_main_password
            + "&language=EN");"""
    urllib2.urlopen(disconnect_url).read()
    subprocess.call("/var/tmp/restartMe.sh", shell=True)
```

Comment: Are you confident that the webserver is consistently handling the request? If `urllib2.urlopen(disconnect_url).read()` fails, then the behavior you describe could happen.

Comment: @BostonJohn: YES 100% sure, i have webserver tail -f /etc/httpd/logs/access_log open next to me while pressing buttons on python. There i get hits but then other statements does not work. Very weired.

Comment: if i remove the .read() it works but still very slow to execute the last statement. How can i run the urlopen as another process so that it does not require me to wait.

Comment: I would advise you to do what you did in the answer you wrote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have to use as multi-threading.

```
import threading

def task1():
  urllib2.urlopen(blabla)

class bla:
  def disconnectButton(self, w):
    print "Window Resize"
    self.buttononTop()
    #urllib2.urlopen(disconnect_url).read()
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=task1)
    subprocess.call("/var/tmp/restartMe.sh", shell=True)
```